# Which process(interaction) is more probable?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, large-hadron-collider

I am bit confused with process " $q \bar{q}\rightarrow  g$" and "$q \bar{q}\rightarrow Z^0$". I guess at high energies of LHC, weak interaction is more probable and hence "$q \bar{q}\rightarrow Z^0$" is more probable. But I guess I am wrong with this. Also, is $ q \bar{q}$ annihilation more probable than  $q \bar{q}$ scattering? I have no idea whether nature prefers annihilation over scattering or vice versa and if so, why? (I came across these processes while studying ttbar production. So the gluon I am referring to then decays to t tbar)

Comment: Is $g$ a gluon? You are aware that because of confinement gluons are never observed, right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65346/discussion-on-question-by-kbg-which-processinteraction-is-more-probable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [fundamental interactions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) of elementary particles:

[image: strong]

[image: electromagnetic]

[image: weak]

The column labeled "strength" controls directly the comparative probabilities of scattering. It is part of the coupling entering in the Feynman diagrams that describe the integrals of the scattering.

Gluons are the carriers of strong interactions, and Zs of the weak, so to start with there is an enormous difference in probable scatterings of quark on antiquark to produce a gluon rather than a Z0. The high energy of the LHC increases the probability of Z production because the energy needed for creating an on mass Z is available, but still the difference in the coupling strengths is strongly in favor of the probability of the creation of a gluon.

As the gluon is the carrier of the strong force and the strong coupling dominates in [proton proton](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/101/21002) interactions,  elastic scattering(~25) is smaller than the inelastic one (~73mb) at LHC energies. [W and Z production](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0923.pdf) is of order of nanobarns.

Comment: Sir, am I right in interpreting your last statement "elastic scattering(~25) is smaller than the inelastic one (~73mb) at LHC energies" that $q\bar{q}\rightarrow g$ annihilation is preferred over $q\bar{q}$ scattering through exchange of gluon?

Comment: roughly yes. to go from hadron hadron crossections to quark quark one has to use theoretical models and calculate the crossections through fits of  data to monte carlo events, but order of magnitude the answer is yes.

Comment: Also, Sir by fiducial cross section, do we mean the cross section measured by including detector-dependent selection cuts and also taking into account the inefficiencies of detector as well? Also, experimentally, I guess we would be measuring fiducial cross section (atleast taking selection cuts into account which we can later extrapolate to get exact fiducial cross section)while the total differential cross section is calculated either theoretically or through monte-carlo simulations? Am I right with this?

Comment: yes, the true crossection has to be extrapolated out of the fiducial (detector available) phase space.